# Get username from computer that accesses web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

If I host an ASP.NET web form on a remote server and use the `Security.Principal` class I can get the username of the individual who is logged in on the machine or who clicks the button in the form. However, even if this is done remotely for example through a browser, the returned username will still be the username of whatever account the web form is running under on the web app on that server itself.

Is there a way to get the username of any person who accesses the form and clicks a button from a **client** machine? We use active directory at our institution.

Comment: There is but you have to use WindowsIntegrated authentication (at least for one page that'll grab remote user credentials). Or ask in form for AD credentials and validate them against LDAP on webserver.

Comment: So the authentication methods provided by IIS?

Comment: Have you used any sort of forms or windows authentication in order to get the user to login to your app, if so you should be able to get the User.Identity directly. Or are you running the app under an application pool that has a process Model identity set to a fixed user account?

Comment: I just run the app under a default pool and then if any of the apps I've created need restricted access I disabled the anonymous authentication and then create specific accounts on the server itself and add them to the "add/deny users". Could I enable AD authentication to the web form and then get the username that way?